# Display time data with telerik chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart

We need to visualize the number of forms submitted over a 2 week period where it is broken down by day/hour.

I have the query returning data such as:

[image]

My question is, how do I tell MS chart to display this data?  When I bind it I get the following:
[image]

I'd like it to expand out and show the hours between the dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a List of DateTime objects, each object could add the DateCompletedHour to the DateCompleted value and then bind your chart to the List:

```
        IList<DateTime> ChartData = new List<DateTime>();
        foreach (var row in formDataSource)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(row["DateCompleted"]);
            dt.AddHours(Convert.ToInt16(row["DateCompletedHour"]));
            ChartData.Add(dt);
        }

        FormChart chart = new FormChart();
        chart.DataSource = ChartData;
        chart.DataBind();
```